# How to eport value in combobox to excel file

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel, combobox

I want to export data in a table to an excel file, I am using `table2excel` plugin, it works fine with all values except form combo box value, I want to export only the selected value, how can this be done?

```
function ExportResults()
{
   startDate=document.getElementById("Start_Date").value;
   endDate=document.getElementById("End_Date").value;

   $('#OrderTable').table2excel({
      exclude: ".excludeThisClass",
      name: "Excel Document Name",
      filename: "Search Results (" + startDate + "-" + endDate + ")", //do not include extension
      fileext: ".xls", // MUST use .xls extension, only this will work
   }); 
}
```

[image]